# jqGrid LoadOncomplete

Tags: ajax, jqgrid

Spec: JqGrid 1.11.2
Browser : Firefox 36.0.4

I have successfully be able  to load json data on to a jQGrid  via Ajax technique on click of a button.

Problem : I need some extra data **"userdata"** to be fetched along with the json-data to be loaded on to the page other then the jQGrid.

Grid Data:-

```
{
"total":"1",
"page":"1",
"records":"10",
"userdata":{"selZd":"23","selYd":"22","selXd":"21"},
"rows":[
    {"id":"1","cell":["PDF","J2EEHandbook.pdf","/PDF Handbook.pdf"]} 
       ]
}
```

Ajax-function : -

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $('#buttSerch').click(function() {          
    var newurl = 'Data.jsp?srchword='+  
    $('#srchTxt').val() +'&srchType='+gdsrctp;
    $('#'+ gdivid).jqGrid().setGridParam(
         {url : newurl }).trigger("reloadGrid");

    //?? fetch  userdata    
    });     
});
```

Question : I need to fetch the data "userdata" in the Ajax function 
           How can this be achieved.

with regards
Karthik

Answer (score 0):

The `userdata` can be accessed by usage `getGridParam` method with parameter `"userData"` (!! the case is important it should be `userdata` in the JSON data and `"userData"` in `getGridParam` method):

```
var userdata = $('#'+ gdivid).jqGrid("getGridParam", "userData");
```

Comment: Hi ... I use the same  $(document).ready(function() {      
    $('#buttSerch').click(function() {          
    var newurl = 'Data.jsp?srchword='+  
    $('#srchTxt').val() +'&srchType='+gdsrctp;
    $('#'+ gdivid).jqGrid().setGridParam(
         {url : newurl }).trigger("reloadGrid");
         var userdata = $('#'+ gdivid).jqGrid("getGridParam", "userData");
         alert(userdata..selXd); 
    });     
});   but "alert(userdata..selXd)"  returns Undefined ????

Comment: @N.S.Karthik: Which version of **jqGrid** you use? Why you make `reloadGrid` before getting of `userData`? `userData` is available **after the data are loaded**. It's unclear from the code fragment when you get the response from the server. Only *after processing the server response* (inside of `addJSONData` or `addXmlData`) the `userData` will be set. I recommend you to access `userData` inside of `loadComplete`. Getting of `userData` directly after `reloadGrid` can return `null` at the first loading or old data if no new response are processed or new data if the response are processed.

Comment: @N.S.Karthik: jqGrid 1.11.2 is not exist. You use probably jQuery 1.11.2. You should open jqGrid file and you will the the version in the first comment lines.

Comment: I am confused about using 'loadComplete' ,because the code above is an AJAX function to bind data to Grid by click of the button '$('#buttSerch').click(function()'    The data is of Json format .   The screen has 2  specific components a) a Grid to hold Data b) userdata  info to be filled into the same jsp page......

Comment: Sorry ....@license jqGrid  4.7.0 - jQuery Grid  /
jQuery v1.11.2 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc.

Comment: var newurl = 'Data.jsp?srchword='+  
    $('#srchTxt').val() +'&srchType='+gdsrctp;   of code Posts Data ifo to a jsp page and the Jsp page on return has to ajax the Grid +userdata ....

Comment: @N.S.Karthik: If you use jqGrid 4.7.0 then the comment should don't contain any "jQuery Grid jQuery v1.11.2 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc." part. See [jquery.jqGrid.js](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.js) or [jquery.jqGrid.min.js](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/minified/jquery.jqGrid.min.js). Where you get the strange source? Is it really jqGrid or some another product with the close name? The code which you included just trigger **asynchronous** filling of the grid. Could you include the code which creates jqGrid?

Comment: @N.S.Karthik: By the way jqGrid have no callback with the name `LoadOncomplete`. There are exist `loadComplete` only. See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events).

Comment: "jquery.jqGrid.js"  :  @license jqGrid 4.7.0 - jQuery Grid                                                                                                                                                                                               &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "jquery-1.11.2.min.js" : jQuery v1.11.2 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc.

Comment: which you included just trigger asynchronous filling of the grid   : yes this is the requirement

Answer (score 0):

Code for the Grid 
colNames:['CATEGORY','PAGENO','CONTENTFILENAME','DATEOFCRTE','DATEOFINDEX','SIZEOF','UCODEDTLS','CONTENTEXTN','PATHOFCONTENT','CONTENT','DOCNUM','DOCWIGHT'],
colModel:[
{name:'CATEGORY',index:'true',width:'5',sortable:'true',align:'left',editable: true,formatter:iconColumnFormat },
{name:'PAGENO',index:'true',width:'3',sortable:'true',align:'left',editable: true,  },
{name:'CONTENTFILENAME',index:'true',width:'25',sortable:'true',align:'left',editable: true,  },
{name:'DATEOFCRTE',index:'true',width:'10',sortable:'true',align:'left',editable: true,  },
{name:'DATEOFINDEX',index:'true',width:'10',sortable:'true',align:'left',editable: true,  },
{name:'SIZEOF',index:'true',width:'8',sortable:'true',align:'left',editable: true,  },
{name:'UCODEDTLS',index:'true',width:'8',sortable:'true',align:'left',editable: true,  },
{name:'CONTENTEXTN',index:'true',width:'5',sortable:'true',align:'left',editable: true,  },
{name:'PATHOFCONTENT',index:'true',width:'40',sortable:'true',align:'left',editable: true,  },
{name:'CONTENT',index:'true',width:'15',sortable:'true',align:'left',editable: true,formatter:linkdialogColumnFormat },
{name:'DOCNUM',index:'true',width:'5',sortable:'true',align:'left',editable: true,  },
{name:'DOCWIGHT',index:'true',width:'8',sortable:'true',align:'left',editable: true,  }
],
url:'dummyData.jsp',
datatype:"json",
jsonReader:{root:'rows',page:'page',total:'total',records:'records', userdata:'userdata',cell:'cell',id:'id'},
loadComplete:'urlxdatafetch',
mtype:'GET',
hidegrid:false,
loadonce:true,
caption:"'Grid from Database -jsonstring'",
width:1200,
height:200,
rowNum:"10",
rowList:[10,50,100],
sortable:true,
sortorder:"desc",
shrinkToFit:true,
autowidth:true,
rownumbers:true,
footerrow:false,
viewsortcols:true,
viewrecords:true,
gridview:true,
autoencode:"true",
multiselect:true,
loadtext:"Data-Organized",

pager  : "#pgerId",

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/content/script/jqCompnents/jQuery/themes/vader/jquery-ui.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/content/script/jqCompnents/jQuery/css/ui.multiselect.css" >

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="/content/script/jqCompnents/jQuery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>


<!-- jQuery.ui Tabs,Dialogs -->

<script src="/content/script/jqCompnents/jQuery/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="/content/script/jqCompnents/jQuery/ui.multiselect.js"></script>